# How can I create string indexing instead of numbers from dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I want to create unique row identifiers , in place of the index column, from the contents present in the columns of a dataframe.

For example,

```
import pandas as pd
from pprint import pprint

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["ID", "Animal", "Weight", "Description"])
df["ID"] = ["Qw9457", "gft878"]
df["Animal"] = ["Mouse", "Lion"]
df["Weight"] = [20, 67]
df["Description"] = ["hsdg rie",  "gtre sjdhi"]
pprint(df)

Output:
       ID Animal  Weight Description
0  Qw9457  Mouse      20    hsdg rie
1  gft878   Lion      67  gtre sjdhi
```

I'd prefer to rename the index column using the contents present in the rest of the columns,
for example :

```
df.index = ["MQwrie", "Lgfgt"]
```

I would like to know if there are nice ways to programmatically generate
row identifiers(i.e index column) from the contents of columns.

Comment: You can already use the ID column or a new column called indexing with what you need to put in it to use to call the corresponding row

Comment: Yes, I can do that. I am trying to automate this step.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to generate an index based on bits of the data in each column, you can piece it together using Series operations and then assign the index.  Below, we use the first letter of the animal's name, the weight, and the first word of the description as a new index.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': ['Qw9457', 'gft878'],
                   'Animal': ['Mouse', 'Lion'],
                   'Weight': [20, 67],
                   'Description': ['hsdg rie', 'gtre sjdhi']})

# create new index from data in df, assign as index
ix = df.Animal.str[0] + df.Weight.astype(str) + df.Description.str.split().str.get(0)
df_new = df.set_index(ix)

df_new
# returns:
             ID Animal  Weight Description
M20hsdg  Qw9457  Mouse      20    hsdg rie
L67gtre  gft878   Lion      67  gtre sjdhi
```

EDIT:
Yes, you add the current row number (starting at zero), you can use:

```
ix = (
    df.Animal.str[0] 
    + df.Weight.astype(str)
    + df.Description.str.split().str.get(0)
    + df.index.astype(str).str.zfill(3)
)

df_new = df.set_index(ix)
df_new
#returns:
                ID Animal  Weight Description
M20hsdg000  Qw9457  Mouse      20    hsdg rie
L67gtre001  gft878   Lion      67  gtre sjdhi
```

Comment: can we append these with numbers at the end based on number of rows in the dataframe so that the index column looks like a sequence? Say, there are hundred rows, `ix = [ "M20hsdg001". "L67gtre002"]`